# Pointer to class method

Tags: c++, class, methods, pointers

I'm trying to have pointer to class methods, so I have something like:

```
class foo {
    public:
    static void bar() {
}
};

void (foo::*bar)() = &foo::bar;
```

That doesn't compile :( I get:

```
> error: cannot convert ‘void (*)()’ to
> ‘void (foo::*)()’ in
> initialization
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A static method, when used by name rather than called, is a pointer.

```
void (*bar)() = foo::bar; // used as a name, it's a function pointer
...
bar(); // calls it
```

Comment: tnx a lot for quick answer :)

Comment: No, it's not a pointer, it's a function. It does *decay* to a function pointer though.

Comment: Why the other questions have the & in front of foo::bar. Is the reference operator finally necessary or not?

Answer (score 2):

A pointer to a *static* member has the same type as a pointer to non-member.

Try:

```
void (*bar)() = &foo::bar;
```

Comment: tnx a lot for quick answer :)

Answer (score 2):

`bar()` is a static function, in other words there is not `this` parameter.

```
void (*myfunptr)() = &(foo::bar);
```

Comment: tnx a lot for quick answer :)